# Installing opencv GEM - extconf.rb error

Tags: ruby, opencv, extconf.rb

I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now, so PLEASE help!

I run MAC OS X(10.7.5), with Xcode(4.5.2) and Command Line Tools installed. Ruby 1.9.3-p362, RVM 1.17.8. apple-gcc42 has also been installed. I use Homebrew for installations.

When I try to install the Opencv gem, I get the following error:

```
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/samanthacabral/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby
--with-opencv-dir
--without-opencv-dir
--with-opencv-include
--without-opencv-include=${opencv-dir}/include
--with-opencv-lib
--without-opencv-lib=${opencv-dir}/lib
--with-ffcall-dir
--without-ffcall-dir
--with-ffcall-include
--without-ffcall-include=${ffcall-dir}/include
--with-ffcall-lib
--without-ffcall-lib=${ffcall-dir}/lib
--with-cxcorelib
--without-cxcorelib
extconf.rb:32:in `block in <main>': libcxcore not found. (RuntimeError)
from extconf.rb:31:in `each'
from extconf.rb:31:in `<main>'
```

I have tried reinstalling RVM a couple of times and making some of the other changes recommended in similar questions.

My gem file compiles just fine without the opencv gem, but I am having similar issues with RMagick (showing an extconf.rb error).

What should I do?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else experiences this, I had better similar problems on OS X and had better luck with the ruby-opencv gem.